How to get the sum in array of objects in Laravel eloquent
I have this Array of objects where I wanna sum up the quantity having the same barcode. Am using Laravel if you can give me a eloquent solution that will be great.
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "barcode": "555",
    "description": "pencil",
    "quantity": "3",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "barcode": "555",
    "description": "pencil",
    "quantity": "1",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "paper",
    "quantity": "1",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "paper",
    "quantity": "8",
  },

]

desired output
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "barcode": "555",
    "description": "pencil",
    "qty": "4",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "barcode": "123",
    "description": "pencil",
    "qty": "9",
  }
]

thanks

You can use the collection's groupBy and map (or flatMap) methods.
$collection
    ->groupBy('barcode')
    ->map(fn ($group, $key) => [
        'id' => $group->first()['id'],
        'barcode' => $group->first()['barcode'],
        'description' => $group->first()['description'],
        'qty' => $group->sum('qty'),
    ])
    ->values();


Thanks for the feedback, but am only getting one array and am not getting the sum. based on the example i posted it should be 2 arrays.

Yeah, my mistake. Instead of flatMap use map
and append values
